# hangouts, html5 initiative

Tags: android, ios, html, google-hangouts

I am wondering is there any initiatives anywhere to create a html5 api for hangouts?
I simply do not want to create different apps for android and ios as well (to be frank I am having quite the difficulty to find a starting point, if you do have a pointer please do not hesitate to share)

Thanks

Comment: How about https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/ ?

Comment: Not really what I wanted but thanks for helping me out

Comment: there are no way to create hangout extension/app for iso/android.you can create only for pc-platform

Comment: :'( still thanks for informing me